# Is it possible to use `event.target.label` in `html option label` argument value `onChange`?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

The value of `event.target.value` is displayed when outputting it to `console.log`.
`event.target.label` is not printed.
I want to print the value of `label` in `option` , but I am not sure how to do it.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
const [label, setLabel] = useState<string>("");

const onChangeInteger = (
    index: number,
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    if (event.target.name === "IntegerId") {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      setValue(event.target.value); 
    }

    if (event.target.name === "IntegerText") {
      console.log(event.target.label); 
      setLabel(event.target.label);
    }

  };

return (

    <input
          type="text"
          list="Lists"
          name="IntegerId"
          onChange={(event) => onChangeInteger(index, event)}
          value={value}
      />

     <input
          type="text"
          list="Lists"
          name="IntegerText"
          onChange={(event) => onChangeInteger(index, event)}
          value={label}
      />

<datalist id="Lists">
    <option label="Chocolate" value="1">
    <option label="Coconut" value="2">
    <option label="Mint" value="3">
    <option label="Strawberry" value="4">
    <option label="Vanilla" value="5">
</datalist>
)
```

Comment: perhaps `event.target.getAttribute('label')` would be more appropriate